# local python app tries to connect to localhost as 192.168.X.X

Tags: python, mysql, tcp, localhost

I am working on a python app locally and I am encountering a strange bug - I just reinstalled my PC and previously I didn't have this issue so I am a bit clueless.

The python app uses mysql.connector and when I run my app I get the following error message:

1130: Host '192.168.X.XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

Why does my locally running app try to connect to my local mysql server using my private ip address?

The documentation says: By default, Connector/Python tries to connect to a MySQL server running on the local host using TCP/IP. The host argument defaults to IP address 127.0.0.1 and port to 3306. - so it shouldn't do that really.

I am pretty noob with server configuration and TCP/IP so please if you have a solution step-by-step!

Comment: Sounds like it's an issue with your mysql server: it's got some sort of security permission set so that things can't connect to it. Is the server running on the same IP address as your python app?

Comment: Yes it should be running on the same IP as it's the same device, no? The python app should connect as 127.0.0.1 to the mysql server on 127.0.0.1 and there shouldn't be any connectivity issues!?

Comment: @thenubian Try to take the python application out of the equation.  Use the connection parameters configured in your python application via the mysql command line client and see if you have the same error.  It seems like the error you referenced points to an issue with the mysql users table entries.